# Vuetify and Bootstrap grid conflicts only locally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vuetify.js, grid-system

I have a Vue project in which I'm transitioning from bootstrap to Vuetify, but they need to coexist for a while.

The problem is that Vuetify mixin.sass is overwriting the padding in the grid columns of bootstrap adding padding top and bottom by 12px, but when the project is promoted this padding doesn't exist any more and everything is vertically shrunk.

How can I avoid the overwriting?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5adEY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h27BZ.png)

"bootstrap": "^3.3.8"
"vuetify": "^2.2.25"

Comment: Have you figured out a solution yet ? I am facing the same issue right now

Comment: We didn't fix it at all, but we implement a hacky way to solve it, by adding a sass file, I added it in [codepen](https://codepen.io/amicavi/pen/xxRmyJb?editors=0110) to share it with you